# Can't get Roslyn compiled executable working

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, roslyn

I'm compiling this code with Visual Studio and with Roslyn (programically).
This is .NET 6.0 code.

```
    using System;
    
    namespace test
    {
        internal static class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Test");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

When i compile it with Visual Studio, code is working. Console is writing "Test" output.
But when i compile it with Roslyn, program compiles, but an error occures when i launch the program.
Error:
`Unhandled exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The specified file could not be found.`

Roslyn code:

```
                var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source);

                var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("program.exe")
                    .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication))
                    .AddReferences(Net60.References.All)
                    .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);

                EmitResult emitResult = compilation.Emit(Path.Combine(path, "program.exe"));

                if (emitResult.Success)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Compiled.");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"The compiler has encountered {emitResult.Diagnostics.Length} errors", "Errors while compiling");
                    foreach (var diagnostic in emitResult.Diagnostics)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show($"{diagnostic.GetMessage()}\nLine: {diagnostic.Location.GetLineSpan().StartLinePosition.Line} - Column: {diagnostic.Location.GetLineSpan().StartLinePosition.Character}", "Error");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Your output type is "WindowsApplication" so no console will be created. If you run the executable manually, does it still run? Can you run it under a debugger?

Comment: Also note that if you're trying to build an executable for .NET 6 there's more to the story -- the actual .exe isn't necessarily produced by Roslyn in that case.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski ok, i updated roslyn. Now when i launch the program, console launches but there's an error.